# How do i add more than one objects to a database using for each

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

i need to add an object to a database several times with a different Sku code.

I have the Sku code changing in the for each loop but i don't know how to add the products to the database in the same method without getting this error, 
[image: Error]
i think i might need to make it async but not sure how.

here is the code

```
public static PetersContext db = new PetersContext();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sizeList = from ProductSizes in db.Sizes
                       where ProductSizes.SizeScale == 1//product.SizeScale.SizeScaleId
                       select (ProductSizes.SizeDesc);

        var products = from Product in db.Products
                       select Product;

        Product p1 = new Product()
        {
            ProductBrand = 1,
            ProductCode = "Ts102",
            CostPrice = 1,
            SellPrice = 2,
            ProductDescription = "Ted Smith Shirt",
            ProductSeason = 1,
            ProductType = 1,
        };
        foreach (var size in sizeList)
        {
            p1.ProductSkus = (p1.ProductCode + p1.ProductBrand.ToString() + p1.ProductColour.ToString() + size.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(p1.ProductSkus);
            db.Products.Add(p1);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you put `db.SaveChanges` outside the loop?

Comment: I can not see the original type of exception, but there is no scenario I can think of where making something async would cause less Exceptions, or even fix Exceptions. I do not see why you would think making something that does not work async is in any way, shape or form a good idea.

Comment: Tried putting the save changes outside the loop but it only saves the last object in the loop, iv found a few similar problems here and it seems savechanges doesn't work in a for each.

Comment: here is the full exception     "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.'
"

Comment: You need to post the inner exception as well. That exception gives us no information. @PeterSnee

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable `products` (with lowercase p)? You don't seem to use it, and the list is never realized, meaning it would conflict with whatever products you add during your loop. Either remove it or add `ToList()` to its initialization.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things I would do differently in your approach.

1. You should create your context within a using statement.
2. Move the save changes function outside your for loop.
3. Create your p1 within the loop.

See the changes below:

```
using(var db = new PetersContext()) //open connection
{
    var sizeList = from ProductSizes in db.Sizes
                   where ProductSizes.SizeScale == 1//product.SizeScale.SizeScaleId
                   select (ProductSizes.SizeDesc);

    var products = from Product in db.Products
                   select Product;


    foreach (var size in sizeList)
    {
        Product p1 = new Product() //Moving to inside of loop creates new instance every time
        {
            ProductBrand = 1,
            ProductCode = "Ts102",
            CostPrice = 1,
            SellPrice = 2,
            ProductDescription = "Ted Smith Shirt",
            ProductSeason = 1,
            ProductType = 1,
        };
        p1.ProductSkus = (p1.ProductCode + p1.ProductBrand.ToString() + p1.ProductColour.ToString() + size.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(p1.ProductSkus);
        db.Products.Add(p1);
    }
    db.SaveChanges(); //save changes after everything is done.
}                                                          
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah I fixed it. I did not notice he was trying to use p1 to create a new entity every time.

Answer (score 1):

There are other changes you could make, but the the big one I'm seeing is **there's only one product reference**. That same product object is added to the `product` collection several times in a loop. Each time, the loop also sets a new Sku... but since they are all the *same object*, the references from prior iterations of the loop reflect the new data.

To fix this, you need a new product object each time through the loop. You can offset that performance by moving the `db.SaveChanges()` call to *after* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the fact your foreach loop is evaluating the query during the loop when you are trying to call Savechanges() which wants to generate another transaction.

If you just change your SizeList and Product queries to have .ToList() at the end, this will force evaluation and you will then be using lists in your foreach, not a transactional query.

Updated to reflect the comments:

Looking at your code it looks like the ProductSku is a property of Product - you should perhaps consider making SKU a separate table so that you don't need to repeat all the standard product properties.  However, to give what I think you are asking for you need something like this;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (PetersContext db = new PetersContext()) {
        var sizeList = from ProductSizes in db.Sizes
                       where ProductSizes.SizeScale == 1//product.SizeScale.SizeScaleId
                       select (ProductSizes.SizeDesc);

        var products = from Product in db.Products
                       select Product;

        foreach (var size in sizeList)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                Product newProduct = new Product()
                {
                    ProductSkus = (product.ProductCode + product.ProductBrand.ToString() + product.ProductColour.ToString() + size.ToString()),
                    ProductBrand = product.ProductBrand,
                    ProductCode = product.ProductCode,
                    CostPrice = product.CostPrice,
                    SellPrice = product.SellPrice,
                    ProductDescription = produce.ProductDescription,
                    ProductSeason = product.ProductSeason,
                    ProductType = product.ProductType
                };
                Console.WriteLine(p1.ProductSkus);
                db.Products.Add(newProduct);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

Comment: yep, this is nearly working now, but what i thought would happen was where it says  "p1.ProductSkus = (p1.ProductCode + p1.ProductBrand.ToString() + p1.ProductColour.ToString() + size.ToString());"   I Thought this would loop through the sizes and add each one to the end of the product sku but its using the last size for every product. hope that makes sense

Comment: If you want to loop through every product for every size then you would need another foreach loop inside the size loop that looped through each product.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think so, So the end goal is to create a product for each size in the size scale.In this case S,M,L,XL ... every product will be the same except the Sku which is made up of the ProductCode, ColourCode and the Size string, at the moment it is saving the same product with the same sku for the amount of sizes in the sizeScale.

Comment: @PeterSnee I've updated my answer to show what I think you are trying to do.  Also included the good suggestions from the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yer help people, 
I created a new object in the for each, changed the sku in the new object, i forgot i need to give the products a size so i did that in a linq query in the same loop and added it to a product list, the product was then looped through in another for each and added to the db, it could do with a refactoring but it will do for now, thanks again guys

```
public static PetersContext db = new PetersContext();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sizeList = from ProductSizes in db.Sizes
                       where ProductSizes.SizeScale == 1//product.SizeScale.SizeScaleId
                       select (ProductSizes.SizeDesc);

        var sizeIdList = from ProductSizes in db.Sizes
                         where ProductSizes.SizeScale == 1
                         select (ProductSizes.SizeId);

        var products = from Product in db.Products
                       select Product;

        Product p1 = new Product()
        {
            ProductBrand = 1,
            ProductCode = "Ts102",
            CostPrice = 27,
            SellPrice = 79,
            ProductDescription = "Ted Smith Shirt",
            ProductSeason = 1,
            ProductType = 1,
            ProductColour=1
        };
        IList<Product> newProductList = new List<Product>();
        foreach (var size in sizeList)
        {

            string newSku = (p1.ProductCode + p1.ProductBrand.ToString() + p1.ProductColour.ToString() + (size.ToString()));
            Product newProduct = new Product()
            {
                ProductBrand = p1.ProductBrand,
                ProductCode = p1.ProductCode,
                CostPrice = p1.CostPrice,
                SellPrice = p1.SellPrice,
                ProductDescription = p1.ProductDescription,
                ProductSeason = p1.ProductSeason,
                ProductType = p1.ProductType,
                ProductColour = p1.ProductColour,
                ProductSkus= newSku,
            };
                newProduct.ProductSkus = newSku;

                var SizeId =(from ProductSize in db.Sizes
                                         where ProductSize.SizeDesc == size
                                          select ProductSize.SizeId).First();
            newProduct.ProductSize = SizeId;

            newProductList.Add(newProduct);
        }
        foreach (var product in newProductList)
        {

            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You should be able to really minimize the code using the first example up top. Creating NewProduct, assigning p1 to it, adding p1 to the newProductList and then looping through it again to add it to the database is unnecessary.